# Character Encoding UTF8 Issue when using mb_detect_encoding() with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, multibyte-functions

I am reading an rss feed `http://beersandbeans.com/feed/`

The feeds says it is UTF8 format, and I am using simplepie rss to import the content When i grab the content and store it in `$content` I perform the following:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head><body>
<?php
echo $content;
echo $enc = mb_detect_encoding($content, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1", true);
echo $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8", $enc);
echo $enc = mb_detect_encoding($content, "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1", true);
?>
</body></html>
```

This then produces:

```
..... Camping:     2,000isk/day for 5 days) = $89 .....
ISO-8859-1
..... Camping: Â  Â           2,000isk/day for 5 days) = $89 .....
UTF-8
```

**Why is it outputting the Â ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not specifying "UTF-8,ISO-8859-1" and see what encoding it gives you. It might be detecting ISO-8859-1 because it's the last one in that list, rather than the actual encoding of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Set strict-mode to true in `mb_detect_encoding()`, see http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#102510

Also try http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php instead of `iconv()`

Comment: Tried both of these and no luck :(

Comment: hm, works for me... please edit your code above with your new try

Comment: and what about this: echo $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8"); (without the optional third param)

Comment: 'strict' specifies whether to use the strict encoding detection or not. If not in strict mode, some characters are labeled wrong, because they appear in maybe more than one char set.