# HTML Coding - Removing Â character

Tags: html, character-encoding

I run a very simple html site; the charset is UTF-8 but I don't necessary know what that means but it seems relevant as per other related questions. I looked up another similar question but it dealt in php and also dealt with character substitution whereas mine is more random addition albeit always in the same places. I wrote the text for the page in Word and this causes problems in HTML as I have found out before but I've converted it to plain text and the character reappears in the same places. I copied the HTML text, deleted the character in a new plain text copy, and the character still reappears in those same places when I paste it and re-upload the page. What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634823/character-encoding-utf8-issue

Comment: Perhaps you should go learn what UTF-8 is?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Perhaps, but I've learned what I need to in order to accomplish what I need; the Internet is here to help me fill in the gaps in my knowledge. I don't think learning exactly what UTF-8 is will be anything more than 'interesting.'

Comment: You don't need to study UTF-8 in detail, but you should have some knowledge of what exactly **encodings** are. Then your question would pretty much answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick advises:

1. Do not use Word for html creating/editing;
2. [UTF-8 <sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is encoding for the characters that are not present in ASCII. It is very important on sites which use a language different from English;
3. The problem could be caused by [BOM <sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Use Notepad++, you can set the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I thought BOM at first, but how is a BOM causing this?

Comment: On php pages with BOM on some browsers I saw a strange way of interpreting html. I think it is good not to have it on a page.

Comment: I'm on Mac so I tried TextWrangler (apparently best equivalent for NP++); problem solved. Thank you very much!